# How read text from website like its presented in a browser

Tags: java, browser, text, html, copy-paste

So, sometimes the text presented on a website in a browser window looks nothing like the code that represents the text.

Like & auml; looks like ä. Sometimes its other "distortions".

In my case I cant use standards like UTF_8 or the simple String.replaceAll to solve the problem. So my question is:

How can i simulate the processing of HTML that occurs when viewing a website in a browser? Are there some kind of extreme-light-weight browser i can start and push the website through? Or can i read directly from an open browser window without going through the "HTML-sourcecode"?

I want to extract from a window technically just like i had marked the text with my mouse and pushed ctrl+v.

In java.

**Edit: I not interested in what HTML goes into the browser but what comes out of it on the other side. Sorry but I dont know name for this "postbrowser"-language**

Comment: Can I simulate a browser in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read up on JTidy or some other HTML parser. This will allow you to handle the source code programmatically and get the textual contents relatively easy.

Comment: I have tried them, doesnt solve my problem. I need to simulate a browser in some way.

Comment: Oooh, sounds promising =) Thanks!